# Optimizing disk IO

Tags: c, optimization, io

I have a piece of code that analyzes streams of data from very large (10-100GB) binary files. It works well, so it's time to start optimizing, and currently disk IO is the biggest bottleneck.

There are two types of files in use. The first type of file consists of a stream of 16-bit integers, which must be scaled after I/O to convert to a floating point value which is physically meaningful. I read the file in chunks, and I read in the chunks of data by reading one 16-bit code at a time, performing the required scaling, and then storing the result in an array. Code is below:

```
int64_t read_current_chimera(FILE *input, double *current,
                             int64_t position, int64_t length, chimera *daqsetup)
{
    int64_t test;
    uint16_t iv;

    int64_t i;
    int64_t read = 0;

    if (fseeko64(input, (off64_t)position * sizeof(uint16_t), SEEK_SET))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        test = fread(&iv, sizeof(uint16_t), 1, input);
        if (test == 1)
        {
            read++;
            current[i] = chimera_gain(iv, daqsetup);
        }
        else
        {
            perror("End of file reached");
            break;
        }
    }
    return read;
}
```

The chimera_gain function just takes a 16-bit integer, scales it and returns the double for storage.

The second file type contains 64-bit doubles, but it contains two columns, of which I only need the first. To do this I fread pairs of doubles and discard the second one. The double must also be endian-swapped before use. The code I use to do this is below:

```
int64_t read_current_double(FILE *input, double *current, int64_t position, int64_t length)
{
    int64_t test;
    double iv[2];

    int64_t i;
    int64_t read = 0;

    if (fseeko64(input, (off64_t)position * 2 * sizeof(double), SEEK_SET))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        test = fread(iv, sizeof(double), 2, input);
        if (test == 2)
        {
            read++;
            swapByteOrder((int64_t *)&iv[0]);
            current[i] = iv[0];
        }
        else
        {
            perror("End of file reached: ");
            break;
        }
    }
    return read;
}
```

Can anyone suggest a method of reading these file types that would be significantly faster than what I am currently doing?

Comment: There's nothing you can do to speed up disk I/O. The only thing you can do is try to minimize the amount of I/O you do. Make sure you're not jumping around in the file a lot, but accessing values in the same part of the file together.

Comment: You should read more than one value at a time, to optimize cache usage.

Comment: @Barmar Well, not all methods of disk IO are the same. Using fscanf is much slower than fread, for example. Maybe using fread to read large chunks of data instead of one at a time would make a difference, etc. I don't think I'm out of options yet. I'm aware that the actual IO operations of the HDD aren't something I have control over, but there are almost certainly ways to reduce overhead on the software side.

Comment: @Daniel Margosian That's certainly a possibility, and I could change the scaling/endianswap functions to do their operations on arrays instead of single values. You think it would be a significant optimization?

In the second use case, is there a way to discard every other 64-bit double in the return from fread while reading into a single chunk of memory? Or would I have to simply make another 2d array and only use the first column?

Comment: @KBriggs really depends on the cache behavior/usage on your system, but I would expect it to be worthwhile. You could make two threads, one for I/O and one for the data processing, that way you can start reading the next set of data while the other thread processes the current set. I would recommend using some thread-safe FIFO data structure.

Comment: Physical disk I/O operates in units of disk blocks, it doesn't read individual words.

Comment: Parallelizing is an obvious route toward optimization I could take. There are other parts of the code that would be embarrassingly parallel as well. Getting a decent parallelization library working on Windows seems like a pretty big pain though, since most of the ones I am passingly familiar with are Unix specific. Any suggestions there?


@2501: I was unaware of that forum until now. If a moderator thinks it should be moved there I have no objections.

Comment: @Barmar I take it that's another vote for reading data in larger chunks?

Comment: You don't have to read in larger chunks. If you access a part of the file that has been read recently, it will still be in the kernel's file buffer, so it won't have to go to disk. So it's a vote for locality. You can get some improvement by buffering larger chunks, since you'll minimize system calls, but that's miniscule compared to I/O.

Comment: Data access is all sequential on the first pass (I do two passes through the file - one to identify where the interesting parts are, and a second to analyze those parts in detail). In the first case (the bottleneck) it's just a straight read through the entire file, in order.

Comment: Read your large files from SSD.

Comment: I don't know how to do this efficiently with just the standard C library, but asynchronous/overlapped IO might help: you ask to read a big chunk of memory and you asynchronously read the next big chunk of memory while  you process the first one.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin That would require moving the files onto an SSD first, which ends up more than overtaking any speed boost from the SSD reads.

Comment: @zneak interesting idea. I have no idea what library to use for that but I'll look into it.

Comment: @KBriggs: what is the current speed for these functions in MB/s ?

Comment: Some quick back of the envelope calculations suggests somewhere in the vicinity of 10 MB/s real time. I'm currently profiling the code so I'll be able to give you a better in a little bit, assuming I set this up correctly.

Comment: @chqrlie a quick profiler run on a shorter data set shows 25 MB/s (208 MB read with a total of 8.3 seconds spent in the reading function).

Comment: @KBriggs: Timing I/O is tricky because the disk cache can significantly increase the speed. A much larger subset seems more reasonable to avoid this.  Also try timing a `cat filename > /dev/null` or the Windows equivalent on the same file.  This should be your reference benchmark.  Also try removing the call to `current[i] = chimera_gain(iv, daqsetup);` to see how time is split between I/O and processing.

Comment: Duly noted. See the comments on the accepted solution for some (very encouraging) preliminary results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, it would be useful to use a [profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming))r to identify the [hot spots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_spot_(computer_programming)) in your program.  Based on your description of the problem, you have a lot of overhead going on by the sheer number of freads.  As the files are large there will be a big benefit to increasing the amount of data you read per io.

Convince yourself of this by putting together 2 small programs that read the stream.

```
1) read it as you are in the example above, of 2 doubles.

2) read it the same way, but make it 10,000 doubles.
```

Time both runs a few times, and odds are you will be observe #2 runs much faster.

Best of luck.

Comment: This will be my first optimization attempt, based on this and comments on the OP. Thank you.

Comment: Very good.    To misquote the Bard... Get thee to a profiler.   Every developer needs one.  It will change the way you think about code.

Comment: Also note, `fread` can read up to `INT_MAX` byte chunks (return type is `size_t`), so you can play around with whatever number you can fit in there and see how the optimization goes.

Comment: good to know. I doubt I will ever need chunks of data as large as INT_MAX though.

Comment: Disk reads/writes are best aligned on the block size of the underlying filesystem, which is available as the `st_blksize` member of `struct stat` (see `stat(2)`).  Also, you might consider using `pread(2)`, which combines your seek+read, if you can.

Comment: To improve stream buffering efficiency as well as I/O alignment on disk block boundaries I would make it 8192 or 16384 doubles instead of 10000, if you read from the start of the file.

Comment: @chqrlie - i would consider that a premature optimization.  Once he sees the difference he can play with different values.   The correct answer will vary depending on his environment.

Comment: Yes, I'll implement the chunk read first. Chunk size is editable in a config file so changing that will be easy afterwards. Currently doing a profiler run, and I'll implement these changes when it's finished (few hours). I'll probably be able to post some results/feedback on Monday.

Comment: Wow. Implementing a chunk-reading strategy cut the IO time by almost 75% in my first test on file type 1. That will probably translate to something like a 30-50% reduction in total run-time. Getting it working on type 2 will take a bit more work since the memory architecture will need a bit of a redesign, but for that kind of speed gain, it will be more than worth it.

Comment: 8.3 seconds for that section of the code before, 2.3 seconds after. I'm running a much bigger data set now, but I think this will bump the IO to a distant 3rd place in the list of bottlenecks.

Comment: Yes, after these optimizations disk IO takes up about 10% of the running time of the program, down from 30%. The new bottleneck now takes 60% of the time, so that's the next one to attack.

Comment: Double the block size and try again.  It might be better or worse.   This thing you are seeing where a new hot spot bubbles to the top is normal, and attacking the item at the top of the list, is your best use of time.   What is the nature of the new bottle neck?

Comment: The new bottleneck is a digital bessel filter which is applied to the data stream before processing. The filter_signal() function is here: https://github.com/shadowk29/CUSUM/blob/memopt/bessel.c. Unfortunately I don't think there's a whole lot to be done there.

Comment: calloc_and_check does a memory allocation.  can you make it a large array instead, and just abort on overflow?  There may be opportunity for loop unrolling as well.   Make sure you are compiling with full optimization.   And test large block sizes for the IO.

Comment: There are very few calls to calloc in the program, and none of them contribute to runtime significantly. I don't think there's much to gain there. I can play with unrolling the loops and see what happens. I already compile with -O3