# Optimizing Bessel filter implementation

Tags: c, arrays, caching, optimization

I'm developing a piece of signal processing code for use with my PhD research, and I'm at a stage where I'm starting to profile and optimize my code. Since my last big optimization ([Optimizing Disk IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043715/optimizing-disk-io)), the new bottleneck, taking a whopping 50% of the runtime of the code, is my implementation of a digital low-pass Bessel filter.

What I'm looking for are suggestions for ways to speed up this calculation.

Code is below, along with a breakdown and explanation of what's going on:

```
void filter_signal(double *signal, bessel *lpfilter, int64_t length)
{
    int64_t i;
    int64_t p;
    int64_t end;
    int64_t order = lpfilter->order;
    int64_t padding = lpfilter->padding;
    double *paddedsignal = lpfilter->paddedsignal;
    double *temp = lpfilter->temp;
    double *dcof = lpfilter->dcof;
    double *ccof = lpfilter->ccof;
    end = length+2*(order+padding);
    int64_t imax = order+padding;
    double padval = signal_average(signal,padding);

    memcpy(&paddedsignal[imax],signal,length*sizeof(double));

    for (i=0; i<imax; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = padval;
        paddedsignal[i] = padval;
        paddedsignal[end-1-i] = padval;
        temp[end-1-i] = padval;
    }
    for (i=order; i<end; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = ccof[0]*paddedsignal[i];
        for (p=1; p<=order; p++)
        {
            temp[i] += ccof[p]*paddedsignal[i-p] - dcof[p]*temp[i-p];
        }
    }
    padval = signal_average(&temp[order],padding);
    for (i=0; i<imax; i++)
    {
        paddedsignal[end-1-i] = padval;
        paddedsignal[i] = padval;
    }
    for (i=order; i<end; i++)
    {
        paddedsignal[end-1-i] = ccof[0]*temp[end-1-i];
        for (p=1; p<=order; p++)
        {
            paddedsignal[end-1-i] += ccof[p]*temp[end-1-i+p] - dcof[p]*paddedsignal[end-1-i+p];
        }
    }
    memcpy(signal,&paddedsignal[order+padding],length*sizeof(double));
}
```

First of all: the `signal` array is very large (say up to `length`=1e7 entries, and I might process many thousands of these arrays in a single run), so I'm guessing a lot of the runtime is just spent loading data into the cache, which is where some gains might be made. Bessel filtering works like this: we have some arrays of coefficients (`dcof` and `ccof`) each of length `order`, which will be somewhere between 2 and 10. The filtered signal at each point is a weighted sum of previous points in the array and previous points in the already filtered array, with `ccof` and `dcof` being the weights.

There are two complications: one is that for finite length arrays, filtering like this introduces edge effects. The way around this is to pad the array with average and to discard the padding after filtering, so that the edge effects are gone by the time the actual data begins. The second complication is that filtering introduces a phase shift in the data (the filtered array will be offset by some number of samples from the original array). The way around this is to filter twice: once forward, which removes the high-frequency components of the noise and phase-shifts the data, and then again backwards, which has almost no effect on the frequency components, but reversed the phase shift. Both of these fixes are implemented below.

Stepping through the code in a bit more detail:

```
memcpy(&paddedsignal[imax],signal,length*sizeof(double));

for (i=0; i<imax; i++)
{
    temp[i] = padval;
    paddedsignal[i] = padval;
    paddedsignal[end-1-i] = padval;
    temp[end-1-i] = padval;
}
```

`paddedsignal` is a temporary array that holds `signal` in the middle portion, but which is padded on both ends with `order+padding` samples to avoid edge effects. `temp` is a temporary array with the same dimensions as `paddedsignal`, necessary since it isn't possible to do forward and backward filtering inplace. The padding portion of both is filled with the average of the first few samples, which reduces error.

```
for (i=order; i<end; i++)
{
    temp[i] = ccof[0]*paddedsignal[i];
    for (p=1; p<=order; p++)
    {
        temp[i] += ccof[p]*paddedsignal[i-p] - dcof[p]*temp[i-p];
    }
}
```

This is the forward filtering loop. When it's done, temp will contain the padded, forward-filtered and phase-shifted signal.

```
for (i=order; i<end; i++)
{
    paddedsignal[end-1-i] = ccof[0]*temp[end-1-i];
    for (p=1; p<=order; p++)
    {
        paddedsignal[end-1-i] += ccof[p]*temp[end-1-i+p] - dcof[p]*paddedsignal[end-1-i+p];
    }
}
```

This is the backwards filtering loop, which undoes the phase shift. When it's done, paddedsignal will contain the padded, filtered, and un-phase-shifted data. We then store the central portion back into the signal array and drop the padding.

In particular, I'm wondering if there is any clean way to optimize this to avoid cache misses. A couple of places might be of interest, but I was hoping to get opinions from more experienced programmers before I spend too much time barking up the wrong tree: In the actual filtering loops the value of the filtered array at sample `i` depends on both its own value and the value of the unfiltered arrays at `i-p`. I'm wondering if this is going to be cache-unfriendly? Also, the second loop traverses the array backwards. Is that a problem, speed wise?

Comment: Are those `memcpy` calls really needed. At first look it seems like you could work on the data "in place" in the original location and maybe save a lot of time.

Comment: The signal does need to be padded. I might be able to pad the original signal array before this function call, though, in which case I could save both memcpy calls (and I wouldn't need `temp` anymore, so it would cut memory consumption by about 33%). Good catch!

Comment: I would explore padding before the call. Another option might be to somehow handle the padding separately in an array local to the function.  That will be a bit more logic to keep track of when you're near the edge and going into the other array, but I'd bet those copies are expensive so it might be worth it.

Comment: That's probably a better solution actually. Padding the array before the call would require that I deal with the padding in countless other places in the program, so local padding is definitely preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest trying to eliminate the `memcpy` calls at the beginning and end.  Those are likely expensive operations and it seems like you can do most of your work "in-place" on the original array. I saw your comment about padding - So I'd consider handling that by either building the padding into the original array before calling the method or adding some logic to store the pad values only in an array local to this function.  Generally speaking avoid copies when you can.

Comment: Good suggestion. That will be my first optimization task, and I'll let you know how it goes.